# Invalid JSON exception swallowed by runtime

Tags: azure-functions

It seems that if you send invalid JSON to an Azure Functions HTTP Triggered function, your deserializer will throw an exception (ie Newtonsoft) but the runtime then swallows that error and continues.  This results in your model being injected, but everything is `default`.

[image]

Obviously, I could convert my functions to use HttpRequest rather than the model and try/catch the deserialization myself, but this seems like a weird oversight that maybe I'm just missing something?

The expected behavior would be for the runtime to catch that deserialization exception and then return a 400.

Function signature:

```
public Task<IActionResult> Redacted(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "put", Route = "redacted")] Redacted model,
            ClaimsPrincipal principal)
```

Comment: As the error is saying about the DateTime Conversion error from `string` to `DateTime` format using JSON input formatter, could you provide the block of code to reproduce the issue!

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT I don't think you understand the issue.  The JSON error is occurring inside the runtime; it's not my code.  Ultimately, the question is "how do I get the runtime to return an error instead of injecting an empty model into my endpoint function?"